# QGIS 3.4, Saved project does not load layers

Tags: qgis

With QGIS 3.4 I have created a map with OSM data and installed different styles. I saved and closed the project. A few days later, I wanted to continue working on the project. It is shown to me under "recent projects" too. Now I want to open it, but the project does not load anything. No layers, just a white screen. There is also no query "Defend defective layers". Does anyone have an idea how to get the project up and running again?

Comment: Do you use QGis 3.4.0 and saved the project as `qgz`?

Comment: This occurs if you have special characters like éàèüöäê... in the name of your project or in its path. It's a known bug. Delete or replace the special chars and your project will go on.